# Implementation of Event Aggregator in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

I want to use Event Aggregator to allow communication between presenters on the page. I am using currently this implementation http://kentb.blogspot.com/2008/03/event-hub.html.

But in asp.net I am not sure about side effects which can occur.

Comment: Are you asking a question? Please specify what side effects you are worried about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only side effects I see is that your presenters will have to contain an EventHub and expose method to subscribe and unsubscribe to events. They will also have to implement the ISubscriber interface. Since this interface is generic you will have to mention ISubscriber for each event T you want to them to receive in the class definition which can be very tedious if you want to receive a lot of events.

Comment: I dont have a lot of events, but I am putting event subscribtions in the onload event and unsubscribtions in onunload. I think it wont work for some events which are being rasied directly, like ajax I think many of them dont raise onload.